# Calculating NDVI of ONLY desired region using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi

I want to Calculate NDVI of my Surrounding Area using Landsat 8.

I have Calculated NDVI but it is rather a very big region.

Can NDVI be calculated for a small specified region or can I extract my desired region from calculated NDVI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with ArcGIS Desktop by doing the following:

1. Create polygonal shapefile.
2. Create a polygon that represents the region of your interest.
3. Use [Extract by mask](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-mask.htm) to crop your NDVI raster.

Comment: I have downloaded landsat 8 dataset ,on which band should I use Polygonal shapefile

Comment: You have two options: 1) apply the tool for a whole NDVI file, or 2) apply the tool for each individual band and use cropped rasters to create NDVI.

Comment: I can't find my desired location in downloaded landsat data as map gets blur,is there any way out ?

Comment: @Lucifer Not sure what you mean. It seems that the spatial resolution of Landsat is not enough to recognize your small region.

Comment: Is there any way to solve spatial resolution problem 
I have use pan sharping technique but it was not useful to my extent

Comment: @Lucifer If Landsat's spatial resolution is not enough to recognize your objects - find other satellite images with a lower resolution (for example, WorldView-3): https://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/worldview-3/

Comment: Is WorldView -3 data free ?or buying a high resolution image will solve my problem

Comment: @Lucifer This is a commercial satellite.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a rectangular region in the "environment" of any raster tool. Click on "Environment" (if you use the forms) or set it up using arcpy.env (if you are in Python). Then define the extent that you want (make sure you also ask for snapping the pixels to the input layer)

Comment: Hello,
1. I have downloaded data form USGS EarthExplorer Landsat 8 
2. Using band 5 and band 4 I have calculated NDVI ,but the region is very big and I want NDVI of  my surrounding area ,
what should be my next step?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you mean that you want to clip a raster ? Then see @Mr. Che's answer.

Comment: I have worked on Both Sentinel-2 and Landsat 8 Images but due to less spatial resolution i am unable to zoom as ndvi gets blur . what should be solution to this problem

Comment: sentinel-2 is 10 m. Do you mean that you need better than 10 m resolution on a large extent ? I am afraid that you will have to buy images from commercial satellites (currently the best commercial satellite has a 30 cm resolution, but you could achieve even better resolution from planes or UAVs)

Comment: Yes I need better resolution data ,where Can I get the data and what will be its cost?

Comment: it will depend on the area captured, the cloud cover tolerated and many other factor. Have a look at, e.g. digital globe's worldview, Satimaging's Ikonos or Airbus's SPOT 6 and 7 or Pleiade. Cost will be between 10 and 40$/ square km

Answer (score -1):

clip the raster with the area (shapefile,geojson,geopackage, etc.) you want and then calculate the NDVI

Comment: Thank You for fast reply ,I tried using landsat 8 data set but I can find my desired location in downloaded data ,can you tell me how to clip(which band) for example a specific ground area and then appy ndvi(band5-band 4 )on it